# jasper causing MalformedURLException

Tags: java, jasper-reports

im getting `java.net.MalformedURLException` when writing a jasper file on a network path `\\L15-00042382\fcdu\` but im not getting any error when reading from that path.

another thing i noticed is the file was successfully created in the path but it doesnt contain any data, here's is my code

```
File outputPath;
        byte[] reportBytes;
        InputStream logFileStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(source);
        if (!(outputPath = new File(path)).exists()) {
            outputPath.mkdirs();
        }

        if(param == null){
            param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
        param.put("url", Constant.LOGO);
        param.put("lastRow", array.length);

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath.getPath() + File.separator + outputFileName));

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(logFileStream);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, new JRBeanArrayDataSource(array));

        reportBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        os.write(reportBytes);
        os.close();
```

this code works when i change the path to my local.

can anyone point what im doing wrong here

Comment: Backslash `\\ ` is special character, so maybe you forgot to escape it?, `\\\\L15-00042382\\fcdu\\\`. I even have problem in comment with it : )

Comment: yup, tried that already, no success

Comment: Turn the backslash around and try //L15-00042382/fcdu/

Comment: tried it too, didnt work

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.